# Python raw input directory that has a space is not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I prompt the user for a directory using `raw_input`, it works as long as I have a folder that doesn't have a space in it. new_folder for example works fine but new folder does not work when I use `os.path.isdir`.

I know I could just replace the spaces with no space but then that leads to problems down the road as I'm using the absolute path for things later on. So if I change the actual folder name, it's not going to work.

```
file_directory = raw_input("Drag in a directory:")

    if os.path.isdir(file_directory):
        print 'This is a directory'

    else:
        print '\nYou did not enter a directory. Please input a directory, not a file\n'
```

Why doesn't `os.path.isdir` see a folder with a space as a directory and how can I fix it?

**edit I forgot to mention this is when I run the script in the command line. When I drag in a folder with no spaces, rawinput equals a string with no quotes. When I drag in a folder with spaces it puts quotes around the input which I think is what's messing it up.

[image]

Comment: Give an example of input, pls.

Comment: input would be a folder called New folder

Comment: Raw_input doesn't take from sys.argv, which is the file name dragged onto the exe

Comment: Do you check if the directory exists in the same path you run the script? If not - you should provide the full path

Comment: Your example output has an error message not represented in your code. Please post your whole code sample.

Comment: @2rs2ts updated code

Comment: Cool, and now can you navigate to the `C:\test` directory and run `dir` and tell us if you see `New folder` there?

Comment: @2rs2ts yes, when I navigated and ran dir it worked. I saw both folders.

Comment: Use ``raw_input().strip('"')`` (that's a double quote between two single quotes) to get rid of those quote marks.

Comment: @jasonharper this worked, thanks. Do you have any idea why it puts it in quotes? I think this is more of a windows cmd thing not Python.

Comment: The ability to drag a file/folder into a console window exists primarily to support the command line, which requires quotes (or other form of escaping) for pathnames including spaces.

Comment: Ok great thanks, now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper advised me that "The ability to drag a file/folder into a console window exists primarily to support the command line, which requires quotes (or other form of escaping) for pathnames including spaces".

so raw_input().strip('"') solved the problem.